# Assembly language swapping nibbles

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, mips32

How would you swap values in a 16bit?
ex. x3421 swap to x2431   ex2. xABCD swap to xCBAD
is there a way to do this by only using rotation ,or, xor?

Comment: Since when R, O and L are hexadecimal digits?

Comment: Just giving an example how they change for humour, but I'll give a better, more accurate example

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want because i used an `and` but if you `and` `x3421` with `x2fff` then `or` the result with `x0030` the result is `x2431`

Comment: @James I suppose that it has to work for every example, not just one.

Comment: Your examples are different permutations.

Comment: Cant use andi, have to mainly use rotation ideas. I just dont know how to swap inner nibbles with rotation

Comment: The usual solution is a [delta swap](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/General+Setwise+Operations#Shifting%20Bitboards-Swapping%20Bits) (scroll down a bit), but there's an AND in it. Of course, we can construct an AND out of XOR and OR using DeMorgan, but that is lame.

Comment: Also you can use shifts to separate any nibble (basically emulate `andi` masking) so you can then move them into place one by one.

Comment: How many memory do you have? If unlimited - you can use pre-computed table 256K size, and use y = tab[x]; Or, you can use two tables, 256int each. And compute y = tab1[low_byte(x)] | tab2[high_byte(x)];

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do it.  Let's rotate left and right and or them.  [EDIT] After putting this in someone pointed out that the OP asked about MIPS.  I honestly don't have the energy on Sunday morning to convert this to MIPS using the `ROL $rs, $rd, count` semantics but it's a simple enough transformation. :)

```
mov bx, ax
and ax, 0x0f
ror ax, 4
rol bx, 4
or ax, 0x0f
ror ax, 4
rol bx, 4
or ax, 0x0f
ror ax, 4
rol bx, 4
or ax, 0x0f
```

Comment: Wrong architecture though

Comment: Oops.. :)  I didn't see the MIPS marker..  Still... :)

Comment: I used that type of solution before, be i want to see if it is possible to do it without using 0x0f, so no andi or ori

Comment: There are no instructions that let you get to a nibble.  AND and OR will be required for what you're asking.

Comment: You *do* need `or`, but you can get away without `and`.

Comment: Actually, you can get away without AND by shifting the desired nibble 0,4,8 or 12 bits left (depending on its position in the word), and then 12 bits right.